# python: self.variable within function

Tags: python, function

I am dealing with tutorial Python code focusing on classes and its functions. I am wondering about `self.` method for the variables defined inside the class.

Should I use `self.` only for the variable of `__init__` function (0 function in my example) as well as for other functions using variables that have been defined before (as the result of another functions in the same class)? In my example there is second function that introduce `k`, `y`, and `z` variables to calculate new global variable (`c`), which will be used by next function. Should those `k`, `y`, and `z` be defined as `__init__`. variables or not? What should be the difference between the both?

```
# define the class
class Garage:
    # 0 - define the properties of the object
    # all variables are .self since they are called first time
    def __init__(self, name, value=0, kind='car', color=''):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind
        self.color = color
        self.value = value
       
    # 1- print the properties of the object
    # we are calling the variables defined in the previous function
    # so all variables are self.
    def assembly(self):
         desc_str = "%s is a %s %s worth $%.2f." % (self.name, self.color, self.kind, self.value) 
         return desc_str
         
    # 2 - calculate coeff of its cost
    # ????
    def get_coeff(self,k=1,y=1,z=1):
        #self.k =k
        #self.y =y
        #self.z =z
        global c
        c=k+y+z
        return c
    # 3  use the coeff to calculate the final cost
    # self.value since it was defined in __init__ 
    # c - since it is global value seen in the module
    def get_cost(self):
        return [self.value * c, self.value * c, self.value * c]
        
car1= Garage('fiat',100)
car1.assembly()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self is the representation of the instance of the class, so if we want to access an object attributes the constructor will use self to access the instance arguments.

```
car1= Garage('fiat',100)
## car1.name = self.name == fiat
## car1.value= self.value == 100
```

In the meantime `def get_coeff(self,k=1,y=1,z=1)` is a function where k,y,z are arguments (having as a default value 1) that will be available only locally and can be manipulated / overridden as variables inside this function and putting them within the constructor does not mean anything since they are not part of the CLASS and are used only to perform instructions on the function.